# Are there any good algorithms/papers on detecting adult content in images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'd like to detect bad content from images like Google and Bing doing with SafeSearch. What would be good approaches? It would be great if you can point me to some good papers/algorithms which deal with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your question can be rephrased as *"what are good algorithms for detecting similarities in images"* and there are hundreds of answers to that (which you'll have to research yourself). I'd personally start with convolutional neural networks. Disclaimer: If you have zero knowledge in machine learning, know that there's a lot to read before you can write any useful code.

Answer (score 1):

Google and Bing don't strictly use direct image to reject them from safe search.  It depends on number of factor like name of image, website that has this image etc.

However if you want to look for a algorithm to detect nude images. Look at this problem as what will you do to detect any kind of images. If are interested in doing research look at this [paper](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/papers/ko5.pdf).

and if you are developing a web application look at nude.js

Comment: The paper is rather old. Do you have a newer one? Thank you

Comment: I don't know, why is it so hard to do a quick google search. http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=detect+nudity